# how to make digital ink handwriting stroke smoother like window ink software

Tags: filter, filtering, handwriting, digital-handwritting

I'm developing a Whiteboard software like Windows ink sofeware and Zoom Whiteboard.
But I found handwriting stroke  draw by Window ink is much smoother and Faster(more real-time) than draw by my software,also smoother than Zoom whiteboard.i want kown is there any algorithm to make my line smoother  like windows ink sofeware. in other words how windows ink implement.

i have tried use some filter  algorithm:
1、Filter points that are too close to the previous point in distance
2、Filter points that are too close to the previous point in time
3、Use Google ink-stroke-modeler smoother  https://github.com/google/ink-stroke-modeler
these algorithms works but still can reach the experience like  Windows ink in smoothing and instantaneity.

the black line is drawn by my sofeware,the red line is drawn by my Windows ink sofeware
[image]
[image]

Comment: How many motion events per second do you get when drawing at full speed? (Maybe some default setting reduces their rate before you get them.) Have you printed their timestamp differences, e.g. are they regular? Are you using the timestamps, or just the positions?